# QT Creator missing help files?

Tags: 64-bit, 15.10, qt, qt-creator

I have downloaded the offline installer for Qt 5.5.1 for Linux 64-bit. Whenever QT Creator starts, an error message appears saying that the Help cannot be loaded.

QT/Tools/QtCreator/lib/qtcreator/plugins/libHelp.so: (libgstapp-0.10.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)

[QT Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZo6Z.png)

How can I get the help files? My system is 64bit Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: Did you try playing around with Help > About Plugins?

Comment: @Akiva Yes. In About Plugins, the Help file has an red x.  I tried disabling and enabling it. It does not work. As well, the libHelp.so file is in the folder that it supposed to be in.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need the offline installer for Qt 5? Are you using Qt Creator or the Ubuntu SDK?

Comment: I prefer offline installers in order to quickly reinstall programs on other computers. I am using the QT Creator that came with the offline installer.

Comment: Trying the SDK via the online installer wouldn't be a solution then for you, right? The only time I ever build from source is when I'm developing a plugin for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install some possibly required gstreamer-plugins using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0
```

Comment: This solution also works for Ubuntu 16.04 and Qt Creator 3.5.1 (opensource) Based on Qt 5.5.1.